# Accessing nested JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I have the following JSON:

```
{
 "reviews": [
  {
   "reviewId": "123",
   "authorName": "author",
   "comments": [
    {
     "userComment": {
      "text": "text",
      "lastModified": {
       "seconds": "1580461776",
       "nanos": 1
      },
      "starRating": 5,
      "reviewerLanguage": "GB",
      "appVersionCode": "",
      "appVersionName": "",
      "thumbsUpCount": 0,
      "thumbsDownCount": 0
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

From this all I want to access is the `starRating` (but with the potential for multiple reviews) I have managed to deserialize the JSON into a C# object correctly and have checked this when debugging my code.

So far I have:

```
var appReview = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<appData>(appJson);
var reviews = appReview.Reviews;
int reviewCount = reviews.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < reviewCount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reviews[0].Comments[0].UserComment.StarRating); 
}
```

However I don't just want the star rating of this specific review as in the future there will be more reviews and star ratings, therefore I need to select all of the reviews in the JSON and get an average of the star rating? Because of that, I'm not sure accessing them with the `[0]` index is correct. Hopefully I have explained that well enough - can anyone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: So, each review can have several comments, and each of those comments can have a star rating? So in effect each review can have multiple ratings? That seems very odd - are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using linq then I would suggest something like this:

```
var ratings = appReview.Reviews
                       .SelectMany(r => r.Comments.Select(c => c.UserComment.StarRating));
```

This should get you a list of ratings. This works by selecting the `StarRating` from the `Comments` then `SelectMany` flattens the arrays to a single array.

Then you can use get the average like so:

```
var average = ratings.Average();
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5NtV3f)